# How can I match characters in a string and place a dot next to each character using regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match, str-replace

Please see my code below.

this returns 
**John Doe L. R T**

I want it to return 
**John Doe L. R. T.**

```
$string = "John Doe L R T";

$matches = null;
preg_match('/\b\s[a-zA-z]{1}\b/i', $string, $matches);

foreach ($matches as $match)
{
    $string = str_replace($match, $match.'.',$string);
}

echo $string;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `preg_replace` for that

```
preg_replace('/\b\s[a-zA-z]{1}\b/i', '$0.', $string);
```

The result would be

> John Doe L. R. T.

And you'll probably want to replace that for uppercase-letters only (since they are likely to be names), so you should not use the `i` flag.

```
preg_replace('/\b\s[A-z]{1}\b/', '$0.', $string);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could probably just combine the operations using `preg_replace()`.  Something like this should work:

```
$string = preg_replace('/\b([a-zA-Z])\b/', '$1.', $string);
```

Notice you have two lowercase `z` in your character class, so if you fix that you don't need the `i` modifier.  Also, no need to specify `{1}`.